# execute named org-bable source block from elisp

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I want to execute selected source blocks in the active buffer.
For example for the following org-mode file,

```
#+NAME: snippet1
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
    (message "snippet 1")
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: snippet2
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
    (message "snippet 2")
#+END_SRC
```

I can use

```
(org-babel-execute-buffer)
```

to execute both blocks from elisp, but how can I execute snippet1 without executing snippet2?

I found the following related functions that might help.

```
org-babel-get-src-block-info
org-babel-execute-src-block
```

Any pointers to relevant documentation is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for org-babel is available at http://org-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. And the snippet to interactively select and execute a named block in the current buffer:

```
(save-excursion
  (goto-char
   (org-babel-find-named-block
    (completing-read "Code Block: " (org-babel-src-block-names))))
  (org-babel-execute-src-block-maybe))
```

Comment: I just replaced "(completing-read "Code Block: " (org-babel-src-block-names))))" with "my-block-name" since I didn't need the interactive part. Thanks for the snippet it works great now :).

Answer (score 1):

Much easier than the AA: Using the [built-in function `(org-sbe ...`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/org-sbe.html):

```
* Example using (org-sbe):
#+NAME: snippet1
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var txt="snippet1 was called"
    (message txt)
#+END_SRC

If you want to run the above SCB, you could just place
the curson on the closing bracket ")" of “(org-sbe "snippet1")”,
and just run that with CTRL-x CTRL-e , and here once
more “(org-sbe "snippet1" (txt $"otherMessage"))” with parameters.
Documentation e.g. here:
http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/org-sbe.html
```